# How to add a submenu to a structure like this in the description - Vue, Quasar

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to add a submenu from a javascriot file.

Default menu works perfectly, but I don't know if it is possible to assign a submenu using that same structure.

```
export const getTabsMdl = () => {
  let r = null
  r = [
      { name: 'Saldo', icon: 'receipt', to: '/saldo' },
      { name: 'Vendas', icon: 'receipt', to: '/vendas' },
      { name: 'Account', icon: 'assignment', to: '/conta' },
      { name: 'Clients', icon: 'supervisor_account', to: '/clientes' },
      { name: 'More', [{ name: 'Sub-Item', icon: 'autorenew', to: '/sub-01' }] }
  return r
}

<q-route-tab
                  v-for="(bTab, bTIndex) in getTabsMdl()"
                  :to="bTab.to"
                  :label="bTab.name"
                  :name="bTab.name"
                  :icon="bTab.icon"
                  :key="bTIndex"
                  no-caps
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

In Quasar, you can define hierarchy of menus.

Please check this one.

https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/blob/dev/docs/src/examples/QMenu/MenuInMenu.vue